# How to resolve 403 forbidden path error in nginx?

Tags: api, nginx, http-status-code-403

I have two applications. One is hosted on apache web server and another on nginx.

Application hosted on nginx has proper access and the firewall is inactive. While the application hosted on Apache tries to reach the api that is exposed by nginx, it gets a "403 forbidden path" error:

[image]

However, while accessing the api directly, it works fine. (Please refer attachment for details.)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show how your Nginx server is configured, so the community can help you?

Comment: The successful direct API request has an extra component in the URL path: the "1583...2000" string appears twice.  Is that intentional?